# Where to see the recent changes/actions on a computer?

Tags: linux, unix, logging

I log on to a lot of different servers at work to do some tasks and install new software. However, sometimes I find myself wanting to know what has been done to the computer recently. This usually involves me going through log files and just observing the filesystem for new folders/files (usually in /tmp).

Is there some kind of a master log file which logs all (or nearly all) "activity" on the computer. Even getting a list of most recent command line 'history' from different users would be helpful to see what they did in the last couple hours. I only need to know the big things:

- new software installs
- important files being changed
- new users/groups being made

Am I asking for too much from my system? If this doesn't exist I might just develop a tool to do it. In that case, which files should I be looking at to extract the information I want?

Comment: I bet there are a few packages in existence for this kind of thing. I suppose a 'tripwire' would even help to some extent. Or perhaps SELinux has some extra logging in it - anyway - this isn't an answer since I'm not sure.

Comment: Check out Unix Accounting.

Comment: UNIX accounting is very cool, thanks for the reference.

Comment: Consider answering yourself with what/how you use accounting. I know very little about it besides that it exists, and how you use it in detail to achieve your goal would be interesting.

Comment: @Daniel Beck: Accounting seems to be what I'm looking for. If you'd post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix accounting helps you in figuring out who did what, when.

On my OS X system, I can use e.g. `last`, `lastcomm` and `sa` to get some historical user activity information. I believe Linux systems have even more commands available.

Comment: I will also vote this up in one hour. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Damn. I sure didn't issue any `find` or `rm` calls this morning. Scary. I better to ignore this...